# ng-repeat function call returniing negative value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am calling a function from ng-repeat and I want the balance to be calculated from a function call while ng-repeat is being rendered in angularjs. But the problem is ng-repeat calls that function more times than the length of the array. How do I get the correct balance value and why is this happening?

here is the [plunkr](http://http:/http://plnkr.co/edit/bdWVU8Q9pVmXx6aZx2mO?p=preview)

Comment: plunkr isn't working.

Comment: angular expressions in the view may be called many more times than the ngRepeat iterations. This is the way the digest works. To fix this move your function call in your ngController, and bind it to a scope property. In your view, bind to the scope property.

Comment: try this http://plnkr.co/edit/bdWVU8Q9pVmXx6aZx2mO?p=preview

Comment: If I move function in controller and use scope property then how will function be called in ng-repeat's every iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do..  Because anything wrapped in double curly braces is an expression that gets evaluated at least once during the digest cycle and your function may get called repeatedly.

```
$scope.getBalance=function(item,index){
     return item.bal ? item.bal : (bal=item.bal =bal-item.amount);
}
```

It makes no guarantee about the number of calls.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xPNI6v3a0XZOd8zFXkPi?p=preview)

Comment: item deosnt have bal as its property then what is item.bal?

Comment: You can simply add propertes at runtime like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
    <table border="1" ng-init="bal = 3000">
          <tr><th>Date</th><th>Name</th><th>Amount Paid</th><th>Balance</th></tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in services">
             <td>{{item.date | date}}</td>
             <td>{{item.service_item}}</td><td>{{item.amount}}</td>
             <td>{{ bal-item.amount }}</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
```

and remove the function from the script.

here's the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fBs9nKRTMAeEtlOX5NPC?p=preview)

**EDIT :** [plunker-2](http://plnkr.co/edit/FK67SALAodRQPWbRCwIb?p=preview) if you want update the balance on every instance of ng-repeat.

Here we use ng-init which is same(almost) as onload.

Comment: But totalcharge should get deducted everytime the amount is paid..in last row the balance should be  totalcharge-sum(amount column)

Comment: so if you want to initialize bal once and remove the specific amount from the same in each iteration then use ng-init, i'll update the plunker

Comment: Love the `ng-init` solution, but is there a way to re-initialize when the array changes? (when the `amount`s change, not when we add elements, which I'm guessing will be correctly computed when they are added)

Comment: pardon but i don't understand what you mean by "array changes", if you want to include another `ng-repeat` then just put it inside a `<div  ng-init="bal =3000">` .

Answer (score 0):

Just pre-compute a balances array. In your controller, replace

```
var bal=3000;
$scope.getBalance=function(item,index){
  bal=bal-item.amount;
  return bal;
}
```

with something like:

```
var bal=3000;
var balances = [];
function initBalances() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.services.length; i++) {
    balances[i] = ((i > 0) ? balances[i-1] : bal) - $scope.services[i].amount;
  }
}
initBalances(); // also re-run on every amount change

$scope.getBalance = function(item, index) {
  return balances[index];
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.services = [{
    "id": 315,
    "service_item": "Test service 1",
    "date": "2015-12-05T18:30:00.000Z",
    "amount": 400,
    "balance": 0
  }, {
    "id": 316,
    "service_item": "Test service 2",
    "date": "2015-12-05T18:30:00.000Z",
    "amount": 100,
    "balance": 0
  }, {
    "id": 317,
    "service_item": "Test service 3",
    "date": "2015-12-05T18:30:00.000Z",
    "amount": 200,
    "balance": 0
  }, {
    "id": 318,
    "service_item": "Test service 4",
    "date": "2015-12-05T18:30:00.000Z",
    "amount": 400,
    "balance": 0
  }, {
    "id": 319,
    "service_item": "Test service 5",
    "date": "2015-12-05T18:30:00.000Z",
    "amount": 1000,
    "balance": 0
  }];

  var bal = 3000;
  var balances = [];
  function initBalances() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.services.length; i++) {
      balances[i] = ((i > 0) ? balances[i - 1] : bal) - $scope.services[i].amount;
    }
  }
  initBalances();

  $scope.getBalance = function(item, index) {
    return balances[index];
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
  <h1>Total Charge is 3000</h1>

  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount Paid</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in services">
      <td>{{item.date | date}}</td>
      <td>{{item.service_item}}</td>
      <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
      <td>{{ getBalance(item,$index) }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```